# Есть ли jquery dateFormat, который бы использовал имена дней недели из массива dayNamesMin ?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Если передать dateFormat: 'dd MM yy, D' , то будет '1 Сентября 2011, чтв' , 'чтв' берется из массива dayNamesShort. Если передать dateFormat: 'dd MM yy, DD' , то будет '1 Сентября 2011, Четверг' , 'Четверг' берется из массива dayNames. Что нужно передать в опцию dateFormat для datepicker-a, чтобы в input-е было '1 Сентября 2011, Чт' ? Спасибо..

Answer (score 1):

Из вашего вопроса понял, что вы используете UI/Datepicker. Проще всего в этой ситуации будет переопределить массив dayNamesShort, точнее русскую локализацию, и явно задать необходимые вам сокращения. Либо как другой вариант подыскать другой datepicker, благо на сегодняшний день их великое множество.

P.S. судя по документации в UI/Datepicker не поддерживаются двухбуквенные сокращения дней недели.

Comment: То что вы предлагаете сделать - понятно. Просто было интересно можно ли как-то задействовать массив dayNamesMin из файла локализации, ведь он там есть, и опция для его переопределения у стандартного datepicker-а тоже имеется. Просто думал, что есть какой-то способ его использовать. Но это, конечно, не критично и можно просто переопределить массив dayNamesShort, указав двухбуквенные аббревиатуры. Спасибо.